# Validate JSON schema for expected values

Tags: json, ruby, schema, jsonschema

I have a JSON which I would like to validate.
There are is an object inside an array, within each object there is a property called `name`.

I want 1st validate that there are 3 objects.
And I want to validate the value of each of the property.

```
{
  "hello": [
    {
      "world": "value 1"
    },
    {
      "world": "value 2"
    },
    {
      "world": "value 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to validate that the JSON has `value 1`, `value 2`, `value 3` using a JS0N schema

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Pedro welcome to StackOverflow. I would advise you read the tour guide at https://stackoverflow.com/tour - This explains how to ask questions in a way that fits with purpose of the site and current users expectations. Hopefully you can re-phrase your question to follow those guidelines, including explaining what you have tried so far. Currently it looks like you haven't tried to find an answer.

Comment: You write that "within each object there is a property called `name`" but that obviously is not the case.  Please clarify.  Also, are you asking for a solution using ruby? Are you open to schema languages besides "JSON Schema"?

Answer (score 0):

Using the language of `JSON Extended Structural Schemas` ([JESS](https://bitbucket.org/pkoppstein/jess)), the three requirements could be written in JSON as follows (assuming that you meant `world` rather than `name`):

```
["&",
 { "hello": [ {"world": "string"} ] },
 {"forall": ".[hello]|length", "equal": 3 },
 {"setof": ".[hello][]|.[world]", "supersetof": ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3" ]}
 ]
```

This may not be exactly what you want, e.g. perhaps you want the constraints to be written without reference to the name of the top-level key.  This could be accomplished as follows:

```
["&",
 {"forall": ".[]", "schema":  [ {"world": "string"} ] },
 {"forall": ".[]|length", "equal": 3 },
 {"setof": ".[][]|.[world]", "supersetof": ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3" ]}
 ]
```

Also you could modify the above to express the requirements without preventing the objects from having additional keys.  It all depends on what you really want.

Note that the JESS checker requires [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to run.  There is a ruby gem for jq.